# Multi-Parameter Curly Brace Expansion in Bash

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

How can I use brace-expansion to make the equivalent of *cal 8 2014; cal 9 2014*? *cal {8,9} 2014* expands to *cal 8 9 2014* (showing the 9th of September.) *cal {08 2014,09 2014}* isn't a valid brace expansion, and I can't use *cal {"08 2014","09 2014"}* because that expands to *cal "08 2014" "09 2014"* which is two parameters that obviously don't make sense together here :/ I'm starting to question the utility of brace expansion....

Comment: I don't think you can do this with brace expansion, but I bet you can solve your original problem with cal's `-A` (as in `cal -A 1 8 2014`).

Comment: Brace expansion is useful for the purposes for which it was intended, but those purposes include 'only within the arguments to a single command invocation', whereas you're seeking to invoke two commands.  One 'obvious' solution is `for m in {8,9}; do cal $m 2014; done` (though for just two months, you could write `for m in 8 9; do cal $m 2014; done`, and `seq` is a very useful tool too.

Answer (score 3):

brace-expansion is great, for loops are also great, but add printf|sh to your repertoire and
you'll be in great shape:

```
printf "cal %s 2014\n" {8,9}|sh
```

One clear benefit is you can run it without |sh first to see if it looks right.

You could also escape spaces so that the brace-expansion includes cal and 2014:

```
$ echo cal\ {8,9}\ 2014\;
cal 8 2014; cal 9 2014;
```

And then pipe through sh:

```
$ echo cal\ {8,9}\ 2014\;|sh
    August 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                1  2
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20 21 22 23
24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31
   September 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
    1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30
```

Comment: Programmatically generating code is a minefield -- writing code that pipes to `sh` is a moral equivalent to `eval`, and has all the [security exposure that entails](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). The individual cases shown here are safe, but assuming that'll be true for everyone who uses the practice is risky.